# Java Play unable to prepopulate date field with type="datetime-local"

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am unable to prepopulate a date input field with a type of datetime-local.
I can prepopulate with type date. And I can make a date input field of datetime-local. But I can't do both at the same time. I am using Play 2.5 (for about 2.5 days).

Populates date but without time:

```
@helper.inputDate(searchFilterForm("endDate"), '_label -> "End Date", '_type -> "datetime-local",'step ->"60" )
```

Creates datetime-local format but does not Populate (building custom input field)

```
@helper.input(searchFilterForm("startDate"),'_label -> "Start Date") { (id, name, value,  args) =>
                <input type="datetime-local"  name="@name" id="@id" value="@value" step="60" @toHtmlArgs(args)>
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by making a string representation of the date in the format expected by datetime-local, ie, 2014-01-02T11:42:13.510 . Not the most elegant solution. This is what the dateformatters should do but I couldn't get the play date formatters to do this for me.